# Remote host adding a \ before every " in textarea when PHP posted and saved to SQLite database

Tags: php, sqlite, remote-server, magic-quotes-gpc

The problem does not happen using the home WAMP server. I have tried two remote hosts with the same results.
The textareas' hold some code that can be edited and later used on the website.

Eg:
Correct data in textarea:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
```

After first posting to PHP and SQLite database:

```
<form action=\"login.php\" method=\"post\">
```

And after two posts:

```
<form action=\\\"login.php\\\" method=\\\"post\\\">
```

So when I go to use this changed code, it does not work because of all the .

Note: It is not only `"` but also any `'`

I have checked my PHP and SQLite code and can't find any errors, and because it only happens on remote hosts.
I tried googling but nothing came up. Might be googling this wrong.

Is there a way to fix this or bypass it?

Comment: Which version of PHP does each server run? (Thinking [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php))

Comment: Please google for `magic_quotes`.

Comment: Yes you probably have magic quotes enabled

Answer (score 1):

The remote host probably returns `true` if you call `get_magic_quotes_gpc()`. See http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php

Comment: @Joneseh - you should still investigate further. The magic_quotes feature is deprecated and recommended not to be used. The latest versions of PHP have removed the feature entirely. It is considered a security risk, so if it is switched on, then you may have security problems to watch out for. In addition, other old PHP features have been deprecated for similar reasons in the same timescale. You may have issues with them as well (eg register_globals). To secure your system, make sure your PHP version is up-to-date (at least 5.3) and make sure that any deprecated features are disabled.